# WebSocket закрывает соединение с ошибкой 1006

Tags: c++, websocket, esp32

Есть код простого веб-сервера, взятый [отсюда](https://esp32io.com/tutorials/esp32-websocket)

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include "page.h"

// Create AsyncWebServer object on port 80
AsyncWebServer server(80);

// Create a WebSocket object
AsyncWebSocket ws("/ws");

void handleWebSocketMessage(void *arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len) {
  AwsFrameInfo *info = (AwsFrameInfo*)arg;
  if (info->final && info->index == 0 && info->len == len && info->opcode == WS_TEXT) {
    ws.textAll(String((char*)data));
  }
}

void onEvent(AsyncWebSocket *server, AsyncWebSocketClient *client, AwsEventType type, void *arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len) {
  switch (type) {
    case WS_EVT_CONNECT:
      Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u connected from %s\n", client->id(), client->remoteIP().toString().c_str());
      break;
    case WS_EVT_DISCONNECT:
      Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u disconnected\n", client->id());
      break;
    case WS_EVT_DATA:
      handleWebSocketMessage(arg, data, len);
      break;
    case WS_EVT_PONG:
    case WS_EVT_ERROR:
      break;
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.softAP("Test", NULL, 0, false, 10);

  ws.onEvent(onEvent);
  server.addHandler(&ws);

  // Web Server Root URL
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    String html = HTML_CONTENT;
    request->send(200, "text/html", html);
  });
  // Start server
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  ws.cleanupClients();
}
```

Код страницы, взятый также с ресурса выше:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>ESP32 WebSocket</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.7">
<link rel="icon" href="https://diyables.io/images/page/diyables.svg">
<style>
/* Add some basic styling for the chat window */
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.chat-container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.chat-messages {
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.user-input {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.user-input input {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 5px;
}
.user-input button {
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.websocket {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.websocket button {
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.websocket .label {
  margin-left: auto;
}
  
</style>
<script>
var ws;
var wsm_max_len = 4096; /* bigger length causes uart0 buffer overflow with low speed smart device */

function update_text(text) {
  var chat_messages = document.getElementById("chat-messages");
  chat_messages.innerHTML += text + '<br>';
  chat_messages.scrollTop = chat_messages.scrollHeight;
}

function send_onclick() {
  if(ws != null) {
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    
    if (message) {
      document.getElementById("message").value = "";
      ws.send(message + "\n");
      // You can send the message to the server or process it as needed
    }
  }
}

function connect_onclick() {
  if(ws == null) {
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/ws");
    update_text('<span style="color:blue">Connecting to ws://'+ window.location.host +'/ws</span>');
    document.getElementById("ws_state").innerHTML = "CONNECTING";
    ws.onopen = ws_onopen;
    ws.onclose = ws_onclose;
    ws.onmessage = ws_onmessage;
    ws.onerror = ws_onerror;
  } else
    ws.close();
}

function ws_onerror(err){
    update_text('<span style="color:red">WS ERROR: ' + err.code + '</span>');
}

function ws_onopen() {
  document.getElementById("ws_state").innerHTML = "<span style='color:blue'>CONNECTED</span>";
  document.getElementById("bt_connect").innerHTML = "Disconnect";
  document.getElementById("chat-messages").innerHTML = "";
}

function ws_onclose() {
  document.getElementById("ws_state").innerHTML = "<span style='color:gray'>CLOSED</span>";
  document.getElementById("bt_connect").innerHTML = "Connect";
  ws.onopen = null;
  ws.onclose = null;
  ws.onmessage = null;
  ws = null;
}

function ws_onmessage(e_msg) {
  e_msg = e_msg || window.event; // MessageEvent
  console.log(e_msg.data);
  update_text('<span style="color:blue">' + e_msg.data + '</span>');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="chat-container">
    <h2>ESP32 WebSocket</h2>
    <div class="websocket">
      <button class="connect-button" id="bt_connect" onclick="connect_onclick()">Connect</button>
      <span class="label">WebSocket: <span id="ws_state"><span style="color:blue">CLOSED</span></span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-messages" id="chat-messages"></div>
    <div class="user-input">
      <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Type your message...">
      <button onclick="send_onclick()">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

При тестировании все клиенты одновременно отваливаются с ошибкой 1006 после отправки нескольких сообщений (у всех клиентов значение варьируется).

В моём коде ошибка?
Где можно почитать подробнее про реализацию WebSocket сервера на esp32?